# Shading Problem

Tags: modeling

[image: Click Here For Picture]

How can I correct the shading?

Can someone pls help me with this because I don't know what's going on!

Comment: Being in Edit Mode select the whole mesh (A), then press Ctrl+N to recalculate normals.

Comment: @Gonzou why not add it as an answer? :)